# Unusual C++ syntax

Tags: c++, syntax

In book I found this C++ code:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, caseNo = 1, x[20], y[20];

    ...
}
```

I test this part of code and get this results:

- i = 0;
- j - random number
- caseNo = 1
- x[20] - array with the same values every time
- y[20] - array with random values

I've never see code like this so my question: What this syntax means?

Comment: If you are really asking for syntax meaning, @HolyBlckCat has represented a more readable style in his answer. If you are asking why the variables are with those vals, uninitialized variables's value  is not specified in the standard, so it's not surprising you read whatever from an uninitialized variable, which is part of what UB(undefined behavior) means

Comment: That is a definition of multiple named variables.  `i` and `j` are both uninitialised variables of type `int` (which can represent integral values).  `caseNo` is a variable of type `int`, initialised with the value `1`.  `x` and `y` are both arrays of twenty uninitialised `int`s.     The value of any uninitialised variable (`i`, `j`, any of the elements of `x` or of `y`) is indeterminate (the outputs you have observed are NOT guaranteed) and the act of accessing the value gives undefined behaviour.  Those variables may be assigned values and then used in later code.

Comment: Have you really never seen more than one variable being declared on a single line before?

Comment: Remember that the most dangerous possibility with undefined behavior is the _appearance_ of consistency and pattern which tricks you into expecting that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: default-intialization for objects of fundamental type and arrays of a fundamental type in a function leads to undetermined state of them, using those values would be a problem. Well, save for `caseNo`, that's value-initialization.

Comment: *"What this syntax means?"* -- It means basically what you stated, just drop the parts where the values of `i` and `x` are not seen as random (a random number generator is allowed to spit out zero sometimes). Since you already figured out a reasonably close answer, what specifically is unclear?

Comment: Re: `i = 0;` -- `i`, like `j`, has a [random value](https://xkcd.com/221/). (Well, not actually random, just you and I don't know what the value will be).

Comment: @PeteBecker *"Well, not actually random,"* -- I know what you mean, but it does fit definition 4 at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/random#Adjective): "selected for no particular reason". It's just that people tend to think definition 1 ("unpredictable"). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is equivalent to:

```
int i;
int j;
int caseNo = 1;
int x[20];
int y[20];
```

Reading uninitialized variables (any of those except `caseNo`) causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Moreover the style shown here may make it more immediately visually apparent which values are initialized and which aren't.

Comment: @Chris well, more typical one would be bunch the default-initialized one together, separate from value ones.

Answer (score 0):

All unassigned variables contain random values. Just because they are zero or the same each time doesn't change this.

They may be a particular value because your code leaves those values in memory. But if you restructure your code, then they could contain a different value. So their values are random for all practical purposes.

Be sure to initialize local variables before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

If that syntax is unusual to you, then the book has done a dubious job at describing most basic syntax. Because that would have happen around first three chapters of a good book.

Some books *intentionally* simplify things for brevity assuming that you always can turn toward the reference material for more information. That's what Stroustroup's book does. One hitch here: the reference material, aka ISO standard, exist only in European languages, including English. The official translation to some languages is problematic and sometimes absent, because.. ISO legalism cannot be translated 1:1 in them. But there do exist unofficial ones.

This statement is a declaration of variables inside of a function block (the `{}`), and in standard it is defined as syntax named *declaration-statement: block-declaration : simple declaration*.

Yes, "simple declaration", it's a described as a sequence of declarators for the type followed by comma-separated *list* of *init-declarators* - *init-declarator-list*. These, in their turn, consist of *declarator* and optional *initializer*.

For `x` the `x[20]` is a declarator, which is defined as a declarator of an array.
In case of `caseNo` variable identifier is declarator and `= 1` is  *initializer*. Brace initializers and arguments for a constructor within parenthesis `( )` are also *initializers*.